# google api android verify backend calls

Tags: android, google-api

I'm trying to get this: http://android-developers.blogspot.ro/2013/01/verifying-back-end-calls-from-android.html working.
I created 1 project in google api console and generated 2 oAuth2 client iD's

- Client ID for web applications
  Client ID: XXXXXXXXXX-qngfta2rcn6trlnrg2cmc7ai0qtkd04m.apps.googleusercontent.com
  This id looks strange to me, all examples were like XXXXXXXXXX.apps.googleusercontent.com ?!
- Client ID for installed applications (android)
  I'm using eclipse and got:
  keytool -exportcert -keystore c:\Users\alex.android\debug.keystore -list -v
  XX:07:8D:E4:XX:35:11:21:E9:6F:XX:4D:C5:43:E9:XX:95:B5:XX:XX
  Client ID: XXXXXXXXXX-0lp5o4od3ebkvpr96fsk5jj0tcqj8j5p.apps.googleusercontent.com
  This looks also strange generated client ID

Now, in project:

private static final String SCOPE="audience:server:client_id:{Client ID for web applications}
...

...

AsyncTask

GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(mActivity, mEmail, mScope);

mActivity - my main activity

mEmail - got it with AccountManager

mScope  = SCOPE

The problem is i'm getting null response from google api  and no request in Google api console / Reports ?!?!?

I quess is something from my CLient ID's but i can;t figure what is going wrong, i made all things step by step exactly like in http://android-developers.blogspot.ro/2013/01/verifying-back-end-calls-from-android.html.

Thanks,

Comment: for Client ID for installed applications i also added package name, copy - paste from AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: somehow after i deleted .android folder and reinstalled eclipse, everything works. Don't ask me how!

Comment: Did you figure this out? I am stuck pretty much at the same point

Comment: Hey guys, how you are making the token validation on server? getToken returns fine a pretty huge token, but if i check it on https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/tokeninfo i have an invalid token response

Comment: I check the returned token format and figure out by myself: the getToken() doesn't return a regular oauth access token in this case. Is an ID-Token. There is a very good article about Google authorization and id tokens here: http://www.riskcompletefailure.com/2013/11/client-server-authentication-with-id.html

Comment: Basically, the easiest way to check this token is through url https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/tokeninfo?id_token=the_id_token